# Why does my profile only reflect me having visited 1 consecutive day?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, consecutive-days

Yesterday I was up to 75 consecutive days visited. I upvoted a question yesterday, so it can easily be seen that I was logged in and used SO.

Today, I go to my profile only to see I've been reverted back to day 1. I visit the site pretty much the same time on the weekends... So it can't be a time issue.

Not the end of the world, but I was hoping to achieve the fanatic badge. Any reason why yesterday's activity wouldn't count toward an active day?

Comment: Perhaps you visited right after the next "day" passed by SO standards? Seems unlikely though

Comment: @RyanFu Unless SO changed their standard recently I don't see that being the case, since I typically visit the site at the same time on weekends.

Comment: What you did on site may also have not been enough to qualify as a visit, just loading the site IIRC is not enouth

Comment: SO takes as day an UTC day. If you don't act within 24 hours is likely that you miss the window of opportunity.

Comment: @Nick For me on some days I've just voted and haven't done anything else, and the badge progress updates for me...

Comment: There used to be a lot of these on MSO. Though it is not easy to find the canonical. Perhaps *[Consecutive days problem #97?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482)* or *[What is an SE "day"? When does each day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/)*.